# Overloading logical NOT operator to work as factorial

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, logical-operators, factorial

I've implemented an Integer class with overloaded NOT operator as the following:

```
#ifndef INTEGER_H
#define INTEGET_H

template <typename T>
T factorial(T t)
{
    if (t == 1)
        return 1;

    return t * factorial(t - 1);
}

class Integer
{
private:
    int value;

public:
    Integer(int v) : value{v} {};

    int getValue() const
    {
        return value;
    }

    void operator!()
    {
        value = factorial(value);
    }
};

#endif
```

And it works if I call it before the typename as the following:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Integer.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    Integer i{5};
    !i;
    cout << i.getValue() << endl;
}
```

I want to have the operator on the right side of the typename not on the left side (i! not !i). Is this possible? If so, then how?

Comment: No, this is not possible in C++.

Comment: Because there is no postfix `!` operator in C++. Operator overloading cannot invent new operators in C++, they can only, well, overload the existing ones.

Comment: Operator overload choices for the unary operator on the right side:  `i++` and `i--`.  That is all.

Answer (score 1):

> I want to have the operator on the right side of the typename not on the left side (i! not !i). Is this possible?

No, it isn't. The position of operands of operators is fixed by the language grammar and can't be customized and there is no post-fix `!` operator in it. Also, I assume you mean "operand" instead of "typename", which doesn't make sense in that context since there is no type name in `!i`.

Also, overloading `!` like this is not a good idea. It will confuse everyone reading your code. Not only do you change the meaning of `!` from being a logical negation to something else, but you also make it so that `!` modifies its operand which normal logical operators will never do and also doesn't match the expectation of a mathematical operator.

Comment: Yes. I meant the variable name (x) which is the operand. Sorry about that.

Thank you for your explanation. Now I know why there's no postfix negation operator available.